# Phaser - Change width and height Camera

Tags: phaser-framework

In normal i have canvas size 500x500 and it will create camera size (500,500)
But when i change

```
game.camera.width=5;
game.camera.height=5;
```

then visible area it the same? what will happen when change width and height camera, how to understand that thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based upon [the documentation](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Camera.html#width) and [an older post from the creator of Phaser on the HTML5 Game Dev Forum](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/1424-change-camera-rect/) where he said:

> You're not doing anything wrong, you just can't change the camera dimensions - they match the game size at the moment.

and then in 2015 on the same thread:

> So you can tell if something is within the camera bounds or not. Which is impossible if the camera doesn't have a size.

suggesting that things haven't changed since 2013, and the camera doesn't resize as you're expecting.

Testing as well suggests that things haven't changed either.